# Quick Question on Box2D Contact Listener and Filter and Joints

Tags: java, listener, box2d, contacts

I am relatively new to Box2D and I have a couple simple questions that anyone who has ever used Box2D should be able to answer relatively easily.

1. In my beginContact callback method, I am creating a new Joint and adding it to my world. However, when I do this I get a runtime error. Is this because one is not allowed to create and add new objects to the world in these callback methods?
2. When one is creating a Joint, is there a specific location where the anchor point must be to avoid runtime errors? At the moment, I am averaging the coordinates of all the contact points and using that as my anchor because I want the objects to be welded together at the point where they collide. Am I on the right track? Thoughts? Comments?

Comment: Hahahaha, everything in moderation can be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create joints in beginContact method because the world is in simulation state. You have to keep all the actions you want to do (for example create joints) in some array or any other structure and after `Step` method of `b2World` is finished to perform world-related actions.

If you want a lot of weld joints you will have problems when making complex structure. The simulation will not be good. It's better to create fixture on one of the collided bodies and removing the other one.